# To get count of values with respective attribute values in XML using java

Tags: java, xml

I have an xml file like:

```
<cars>
    <model>maruthi</model>
    <version>alto</version>
</cars>
<cars>
    <model>maruthi</model>
    <version>verna</version>
</cars>
<cars>
    <model>maruthi</model>
    <version>alto</version>
</cars>
```

I need java program where it can read the file and provide out put like,

```
            model/ccar      Alto  verna
            Maruthi           2      1
```

(like Model and count verion for that model..)

Can any one help on this?

Comment: Maybe you could try some SAX parser. see http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/ and show us some code

Comment: Look at xpath support in java.  There are probably a million examples on the web. SO isn't the drive-through window, where you ask for code and it is instantly delivered to you.

Comment: i have checked but there is no loop where i can fetch the count.. is there any other link which can help to my requirment

Comment: Sure i will try again. i tried last time but i am able to get out put like this Maruthi alto Maruthi verna maruthi alto .. so i was not able to loop..didnt get the logic

Comment: NodeList listOfcars = doc.getElementsByTagName("cars");
 int totalcars = listOfcars.getLength(); System.out.println("Total no of cars : " + totalcars);for(int s=0; s<listOfcars.getLength() ; s++){Node Model= listOfcars.item(s);if(model.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
Element modelElement = (Element)model
 NodeList carList = modelElement.getElementsByTagName("model");
Element modelElement = (Element)carList.item(0);
  NodeList carList1 = odelElement.getChildNodes();

Comment: NodeList version = modelElement.getElementsByTagName("version");
Element versionElement = (Element)version.item(0);
 NodeList versionist = versionElement.getChildNodes();
System.out.println("MODEL : " +(Node)carList1.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim() + "version : " +((Node)carlist.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());

Comment: Hi i have added in two parts i am able to print the individual details but not able to get the count of them

Comment: Have u got the required solution ??

Comment: Add the code you tried in the question, not in comments!

Comment: i am not able to get the out put as required. i am to print values like  Maruthi alto 1 Maruthi verna 1 maruthi alto 1 but not able to get out put which i required.. can any one help me or guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice question...This problem taken me back to basics of java.. Here we go for the solution..

Car.java

```
package com.sof.test;

public class Car {
    private String model;
    private String version;
    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {

        if(this.model.equals(((Car)obj).getModel())&&this.version.equals(((Car)obj).getVersion())){

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {

        return  this.model.length()+this.version.length();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return this.model+"\t "+this.version;
    }
}
```

cars.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<cars>
    <model>maruthi</model>
    <version>alto</version>
</cars>
<cars>
    <model>maruthi</model>
    <version>verna</version>
</cars>
<cars>
    <model>maruthi</model>
    <version>verna</version>
</cars>
<cars>
    <model>maruthi</model>
    <version>alto</version>
</cars>
<cars>
    <model>maruthi</model>
    <version>alto</version>
</cars>
<cars>
    <model>honda</model>
    <version>city</version>
</cars>
<cars>
    <model>Audi</model>
    <version>Q7</version>
</cars>
<cars>
    <model>honda</model>
    <version>city</version>
</cars>
</root>
```

Tester.java

```
package com.sof.test;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Car> carsList=new ArrayList<Car>();
        Set<Car> carsset=new HashSet<Car>();
        try {
            File fXmlFile = new File(
                    "D:\\StackOverFlow\\DomParserTest\\src\\com\\sof\\test\\cars.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("cars");
            Car tempCar=null;
            for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
                Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
                if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                    tempCar=new Car();
                    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                    tempCar.setModel(eElement.getElementsByTagName("model").item(0)
                                    .getTextContent());

                    tempCar.setVersion(eElement.getElementsByTagName("version").item(0)
                                    .getTextContent());
                carsList.add(tempCar);
                carsset.add(tempCar);

                }
            }       
        //    System.out.println(carsset.size()+"\t"+carsList.size());   

            System.out.println("**********************************");
            for(Car cs:carsset)
            {               
                int count=0;
                for(Car cl:carsList)
                {   
                    if(cs.equals(cl))
                    {
                        count=count+1;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(cs+"\t"+count);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

output will be:

```
**********************************
Audi     Q7    1
honda     city    2
maruthi     alto    3
maruthi     verna    2
```

let me know if you face any issues....
If you get this accept it as answer :)

Comment: Hii thanks a lot for the solution. but while i am running the Tester.java getting compilation error cannot find symbol  List<Cars> carsList=new ArrayList<Car>(); is there any thing i need to do so that i can resolve this error.. once again thanks for the help

Comment: Hii thanks a lot for the solution. but while i am running the Tester.java getting compilation error cannot find symbol List<Car> carsList=new ArrayList<Car>(); is there any thing i need to do so that i can resolve this error.. once again thanks for the help –

Comment: check List,ArrayList,Car import statements... Make sure that Car is in the same package as Tester.java..And check by changing it to static

Comment: Hi Naren, I tried to include car.java details in Tester.java so that it will be in same code. But i am getting errors i tried to fix that but in vain.. i know i am asking too much help from you.. to be frank i am beginner for java so taking help from you expert guys. is the way i am trying to include details of car.java into tester.java is correct or wrong.. because i want it to be in in file

Comment: update ur question by including the total  code what you are doing...  i will check

Comment: Hi naren.. thanks i am able to get the out put now. I have one more doubt is it also possible to display like  maruthi alto verna                         p                                                   3     2   like will this is also possible.. your suggestions works for me.. let me above thing also possible.. thanks a lot for the help

Comment: yes @user3280677... Raise it as  a new question.. it needs some time

Comment: thanks naren. i have raised new one.

Comment: it seems other reuqest i raised got on hold.